# running a python file in vscode terminal returns 'Python'

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

I am trying to run a python file in terminal of VScode

I tried following code both in 'powershell' and 'cmd'

```
python main.py --path ./checkpoints/vit_side
```

however everytime it returns

```
Python
```

I guess the file i wanted to execute did not work?
Does anybody have any clue why vscode returns nothing but the word 'Python'?

Comment: If the content of the `main.py` it actually runs is something like `print('Python')` that would certainly make sense.

Comment: @Grismar looking through the whold contents in the cloned repository, there is no such thing as printing 'Python' or any other code

Comment: backup your main file and create a new one with the following content only: 
def main():
    print("Hello World!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
what is the output?

Comment: @Kaspatoo it returns "Python" again :(

Comment: do you have more than one main.py file?
is you main.py file laying in folder "./checkpoints/vit_side" ?

use the terminal to change directory to that folder and run "python main.py ." Still the same output? Did you change the contents of that "./checkpoints/vit_side/main.py" file with the content from me above?

Answer (score 0):

try

python -u "your program's path"

and see if it works.